# What is the security risks of increasing the maximum number of HTTP parameter?

Tags: http, tomcat

I want to increase the maximum number of HTTP parameters (maxParameterCount) from 10000  to 20000 in the Tomcat configuration:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html

What is the security risks of increasing the maximum number of HTTP parameters?

Comment: If you need that many parameters, you are certainly not handling html forms with human input. Instead of gazillions of parameters, I'd think about uploading a single structured (e.g. XML) file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone said in a comment, this reeks of bad design.

Anyway, in the past there have been denial of service attacks against server software done by using many parameters that share the same hash as used by the hashing function in the server to convert the parameter list to a dictionary/hashmap. These hash collisions would lead to a wildly increased load in bad server software (that was, most prominent example of that category, the PHP interpreter).

That problem can be mitigated by using an unknown salt for that hash function, so that the attacker can't predict which parameters would lead to a hash collision.

With that many parameters, however, chances are that you generate hash collisions if you just pick random parameter names.

Anyway, the assumption that someone would still be able to DOS a server with that is purely hypothetic.

Comment: Hash bucket collisions are normal and expected in a hash-map. They become a DOS vector when an attacker can manipulate them to direct lots of lookups to the same hash bucket turning O(1) lookups into an O(n) lookup and hence changing the overall complexity from O(n) to O(n²).

Comment: @PeterGreen it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that if you there's no salting of the hash, and you'd allow 20000 HTTP parameters per request, that an attacker might craft highly-colliding payloads. I say it's still a hypothetical threat – In the end, why would a webserver be any worse than the intended application handling 20000 paramter passed in any form?